# Rails failed to push to heroku — invis CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

Any help would be appreciated.

I've been trying to push to heroku, but it keeps on rejecting. It seeems like there is something wrong with my CSS, but I checked it and I don't think anything is wrong.

Here is that part of my CSS:

```
a.w-menu_text { 
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Optima";
}
```

Here is the error:

```
remote: 
remote:        rake aborted!
remote: 
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...family:      "Optima": expected "{", was "";"
remote: 
remote:        (sass):978
remote:
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `" "` from `font-family: "Optima";` it will be

```
font-family: Optima;
```

See the valid syntax [`Optima`](https://www.cssfontstack.com/Optima)

Comment: Thank you very much. This line worked in the past few deployments for some reason, so I probably didn't catch it. I guess it's always the small things that are problematic eh.